# How to convert Illustrator files to EPS via the command line (*nix)

Tags: ghostscript, postscript, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to do batch conversion of AI files to EPS files via the command line on Linux. I'm familiar with using Ghostscript for various EPS and Postscript related tasks. I have been semi successful using the Ghostscript epswrite device, but my understanding is this device is deprecated.

What is the best way to convert Adobe Illustrator files to EPS files via the command line in a *nix environment?

Comment: Illustrator files are allmost eps files. They just have a lot of additional crap on top. So most of the time they will work just as eps would. So most likely just dropping the ai file inside anything that understands eps works. Atleast all my ai files worked without a problem in ghostscript.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone arriving at this question from a search, here is an answer:

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=eps2write -sOutputFile=out.eps input.ai
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf input.ai
```

Look at [the documentation](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Devices.htm) for a list of possible outputs.

My answer here is based on (and is almost a copy-and-paste of) [this answer from askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/101375/).

---

Footnote: I had an `.ai` file that [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) was having trouble opening (wrong colors or layers or something else). Fortunately, I managed to use ghostscript to convert the `.ai` file into `.eps` and `.pdf`, and then Inkscape had no trouble opening these converted versions.

Comment: epswrite is deprecated, and currently does not produce good results.

Comment: @ARolek: According to [Version 9.14 (2014-03-26) News](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/News.htm), `epswrite` has been replaced with `esp2write` (although the old one has not been removed yet). I've updated my answer, thanks!

Comment: you're right, I missed that. I have not used the new eps2write but I will give it a run. the previous epswrite did not produce good results for me.

Comment: I think in the meantime also `eps2write` has been replaced by `ps2write`. When I tried `eps2write` returned an error.

Comment: On the other hand, is there a way to convert EPS to AI using ghostscript?

Answer (score 1):

epswrite isn't (yet) deprecated, but it will be when we finish a version of ps2write which will produce EPS files.

Note that .ai files are not strictly speaking PostScript and therefore are not guaranteed to be suitable for use as input to Ghostscript.

So even using epswrite, there's no guarantee that you can take a .ai file and get a .eps using Ghostscript.

Comment: thanks for the follow up. Is there a way to "print" from the command line using something like CUPS with the input being an AI file and the output being a postscript file?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Illustrator at all. If it can be persuaded to print (or export) to a PostScript file from the command line, then you could write a script. But then, if you can do that, you can have Illustrator export an EPS file....

Comment: That's what I figured. I have not figured out a way to working with Illustrator via the command line. Thanks for the follow up.